# React Native Firebase Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

Could someone help me with that, I don't know why but it doesn't show any data
I am trying to import data from Firebase but it only shows empty space.
When you click on one of these "blank spaces" - the printscreen below - it will take you to the second screen and you will see all the data there.

sorry for my english - i'm in the middle of learning :)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { StyleSheet, ScrollView, ActivityIndicator, View } from 'react-native';
import { ListItem } from 'react-native-elements'
import firebase from '../database/firebaseDb';

class SaveLocations extends Component {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.firestoreRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users');
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      userArr: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribe = this.firestoreRef.onSnapshot(this.getCollection);
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    this.unsubscribe();
  }

  getCollection = (querySnapshot) => {
    const userArr = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((res) => {
      const { coordinates, title, note } = res.data();
      userArr.push({
        key: res.id,
        res,
        coordinates,
        title,
        note,
      });
    });
    this.setState({
      userArr,
      isLoading: false,
    });
  }

  render() {
    if(this.state.isLoading){
      return(
        <View style={styles.preloader}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#FF0000"/>
        </View>
      )
    }    
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
          {
            this.state.userArr.map((item, i) => {
              return (
                <ListItem
                  key={i}
                  chevron
                  bottomDivider
                  title={item.coordinates}
                  subtitle={item.title}
                  onPress={() => {
                  this.props.navigation.navigate
                    ('Details', {userkey: item.key});
                }}/>
              );
            })
          }
          
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

export default SaveLocations;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9v6bl.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to show one of the documents from the `users` collection.

Comment: Is ListItem supposed to render anything? It looks like in their docs they have components as children of ListItem. I think ListItem is just a wrapper.

Comment: I do not think Listitem is supposed to render anything. However, as @FrankvanPuffelen mentioned, it would be usefull to show one document from the user collection.

Comment: I want to show only one document form user collection

Comment: As already said by others, the `ListItem` has it's contents in child components like `ListContent`. Please check the [react-native-elements](https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/listitem) documentation